# cannot get cron job to install

Tags: java, jar, cron, redhat

I have a simple cron job that I would like to run at 3am each morning. For testing purposes, I have set it to run every hour at the 15th minute like so-

```
15 * * * * * java -jar /home/scarter/scripts/java/autobackup.jar
```

I use crontab -e to open the editor, place this line in and save, but I get this error- "/usr/bin/crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XAv3xa":1: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install."
I am not sure what is wrong here, I have been pouring over anything I can find on cron but all seems right in this line. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete one asterisk. It should be

```
15 * * * * java -jar /home/scarter/scripts/java/autobackup.jar
```

because a cronjob is defined as:

> minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon) and day of week
>   (dow)

and the desired command that you wish to be executed.